Diagram chasing in Abelian categories
In an Abelian category, once one has developed the basic tools such as monic-epi factorizations, generalized elements, etc., it seems to me that one can "transplant proofs from Ab". More formally:

Given a commutative diagram in an Abelian category $A$, if the diagram rewritten in Ab commutes, then it also commutes in $A$.

Which would imply, that upon encoutering a diagram, I can just prove that it commutes in Ab, never even mentioning $A$, and as a result conclude that the diagram commutes in $A$.
Is this true?

N.B. The question is phrased so vaguely, since I am purely interested in the "philosophical" conclusion, i.e. whether this transplantation is actually possible, and not in the techincal details.

Yes, as you say, this is because of the calculus of elements in abelian categories. But it can also be deduced from Mitchell's embedding theorem. Notice that every diagram lies in a small abelian subcategory so that theorem can be applied.
But notice that the embedding theorem is overkill. The calculus of elements shows that (almost, see below) whatever we do in the proof for abelian groups, the same will work in any abelian category. Then, the conceptually best way to argue is that we do NOT reduce the claim to the category of abelian groups, but rather understand that our argument directly works in the general setting.
This is how category theory works: we abstract from the examples and example categories. Similarly, we don't always want to reduce theorems about (non-abelian) categories to the category of sets, and instead want to understand that our arguments work in general. Here, the notion of a generalized element is useful. For instance, this can be used to provide the associativity isomorphism between products $A \times (B \times C) \to (A \times B) \times C$ via $(a,(b,c)) \mapsto ((a,b),c)$, in any category.
Back to the case of abelian categories, we  have to be careful what is meant with a statement about a diagram. For example, consider the statement that, for every object $A$ with a (possibly infinite) direct sum $A^{\oplus I}$, if $f,g : B \to A^{\oplus I}$ are two morphisms such that $p_i f = p_i g$ (which we can write as a diagram) for all $i$, then we already have $f=g$ (which we can also write as a diagram). In other words, the projections from the direct sum form a mono-cosink. If the (possibly infinite) product $A^I$ exists, it means that the natural morphism $A^{\oplus I} \to A^I$ is a monomorphism. This is satisfied in the category of abelian groups, and we are probably inclined to think that it is true for every abelian category. Unfortunately, this is not correct. It fails miserably for the dual of the category of abelian groups.
Another example is that for every (infinite) family of epimorphisms $f_i : A_i \to B_i$, also the induced morphism on the products $f : \prod_i A_i \to \prod_i B_i$ is an epimorphism. Again, this is true for abelian groups, but it fails, for example, in the category of abelian sheaves on certain spaces.
So we still have to be careful. There are several additional axioms for abelian categories (AB3, AB4, AB5, AB6, and their duals) that are satisfied for the category of abelian groups, but not for every abelian category. The property with epimorphisms above is AB4*.
If one of these properties is used in a diagram proof needs to be checked on a case-by-case basis unless we use a definition of diagram proofs which ends up very restricted and, as mentioned, can be proven with elements anyway.
